# Kafka:The configuration 'compression.codec' was supplied but isn't a known config

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm running Kafka java client using 0.10.1.0.
As per the configuration suggested here 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression

I put

```
compression.codec=1
```

in producer properties. But when I run, the producer 
The configuration `compression.codec` was supplied but isn't a known config
this warning is shown.

As per the API documentation , http://home.apache.org/~jgus/kafka-0.10.1.0-rc0/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html
only the property

```
compression.type
```

is available.

Also when I put compression.topics, same warning thrown.

Will the property compression.type be enough for compression?

Answer (score 1):

For JVM-based clients, `compression.codec` is the old Scala producer's config which is already removed as of Kafka 0.10, so you should use `compression.type` instead.

Comment: Thank you. compression.topics is removed as well?
Where can I find that information

Comment: I have no idea of what `compression.topics` is.